# Register a user in Azure AD B2C and login with username

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I made an application that creates a user in Azure AD B2C throught Microsoft Graph API

```cs
    var user = new User()
    {
          CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,

          MailNickname = command.DocumentNumber,
          UserPrincipalName = $"{command.DocumentNumber}@*********.onmicrosoft.com",

          DisplayName = command.DisplayName,
          GivenName = command.GivenName,
          Surname = command.Surname,
          Mail = command.Mail,
          MobilePhone = command.MobilePhone,
    
          AccountEnabled = true,
          PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
          {
              Password = "ABCabc123!*.",
              ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true
          },

          CreationType = "LocalAccount",
          PreferredLanguage = "es-ES",

          Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
          {
             new ObjectIdentity()
             {
                SignInType = "userName",
                Issuer = "******.onmicrosoft.com",
                IssuerAssignedId = command.DocumentNumber
            }
        }
    };


    var graphClient = _graphService.GetGraphServiceClient();

    var userCreated = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);
```

After that, we can see the user inside Azure AD B2C

[image]

Then, I want to reset password with specific User Flow created in B2C but it returns an error: An account could not be found for the provided user ID.

[image]

Any suggestion?

NOTE: I tried to register in B2C by using a “User Flow” of “signup” type. I used an username like “00000000A” successfully. I can change password, sign in… So, what’s the difference between creating a user with user flows and Microsoft Graph? Am I making a mistake in the parameters?

Answer (score 2):

From your first screenshot, I can see that you added a user with name `Sergio[...]` and user name `53[...]`. Then I guess that you try to reset the password with `53[...]` as `Id` but `53[...]` is the user name.

When creating a [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0), a guid is generated which is then used as `Id`. You have to use this `Id` or the `userPrincipalName` because these values are unique and enable to identify the specific user.

Here is an example response you get after creating a new user:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "87d349ed-44d7-43e1-9a83-5f2406dee5bd",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "Adele Vance",
    "givenName": "Adele",
    "jobTitle": "Product Marketing Manager",
    "mail": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mobilePhone": "+1 425 555 0109",
    "officeLocation": "18/2111",
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "Vance",
    "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Response copied from [Create a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: yes! I want to login in B2C with an username like _53.._ for this reason I added **userPrincipalName** with the value _53..._ + @*********.onmicrosoft.com (it's mandatory) and  **ObjectIdentity** object with property **IssuerAssignedId**  with value _53..._ too. I mean... login with just the userName